# The problem is creating an abstract CRUD service

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, crud, nest

("typeorm": "^0.3.17")
Hello everyone, I recently switched to NEST JS from ASP NET CORE. I was faced with the problem of creating a GENERIC CRUD service that would perform routine operations. Unfortunately, when creating such a class, I receive a warning from TS:

```
*Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<Entity> | FindOptionsWhere<Entity>[]'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhereProperty<NonNullable<Entity["id"]>, NonNullable<Entity["id"]>>'.ts(2322)
FindOneOptions.d.ts(23, 5): The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type 'FindOneOptions<Entity>'*
```

In code:

```
import { NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DeepPartial, FindOneOptions, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Base } from '../base.entity';

export abstract class CommonService<Entity extends Base, Dto> {
  constructor(private entityRepository: Repository<Entity>) {}

  async create(dto: Dto) {
    const entity = await this.entityRepository.create(dto as DeepPartial<Entity>);
    await this.entityRepository.save(entity);
    return entity;
  }

  async findAll() {
    return this.entityRepository.find();
  }

  async findOne(id: number) {
    const opt: FindOneOptions<Entity> = {
      where: {
        id: id,
      },
    };
    const entity = await this.entityRepository.findOne(opt);

    if (!entity) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Entity with ID ${id} not found`);
    }
    
    return entity;
  }
}
```

Why does this happen? I am extending my entity from the Base class, which has main fields and decorators:

```
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export abstract class Base {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date;
  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at' })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Thank you in advance if you can tell me what my mistake is and how to implement a similar service using Generic.

If I don't use Generic then it's fine, but it defeats my purpose.

Comment: It might help to remove `opt` and do `findOne(id)`, it might work